# ClickOnce Installer for UWP and Winform App

Tags: uwp, clickonce

I have 2 application

1. UWP App
2. Winform Desktop App

I want to create single Click Once Installer for both application So I have added Windows Application Packaging Project. and Added referance of both application .exe file both are added.
now i am going to create app Package and getting these error

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       PRI175: 0x8007000b - Processing Resources failed with error: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.    WapProjTemplate1    GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE  1

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       PRI222: 0xdef00001 - Unspecified error occurred.    WapProjTemplate1    GENERATEPROJECTPRIFILE  1

how to resolve this problem

Comment: Are you following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) to create the Windows Application Packaging Project and package it? When I followed the document, I can package the project successfully. Can you show the detailed steps about your packaging process?

Comment: Yes I am Following this and when i build the package there is no error but when we go to  Create App Packages just Right Click on Project -> Publish than we are getting this error as in the first question

Comment: Do you mean when you just Right Click on Project -> Publish -> Create App Packages you received the error above or when you followed these [steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#generate-an-app-package) and then clicked the Create Button finally, you received the error? In addition, can you tell us what's the version of the Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: Yes @Faywang-MSFT after clicking of Create have this Error. my VS version - Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.6.4

Comment: Is there any Combine Installer Template for UWP and Winform ? because in above suggested link its getting still same error for Winform Packaging

Comment: When I packaged the Windows Application Packaging Project, it worked well. If you re-create a blank uwp and winform app, then package them again, will you receive the same issue?

Comment: Thanks @Faywang-MSFT its working now but i have 2 app in Installer but when in stall installer i can see only 1 App that is set EntryApp how i can open another one app ?

Comment: When i Installed this Package uwp application protocol is not working.only entry app winform app running but i am using protocol to open uwp app but protocol not installing ?

Comment: When you installed the package, it will run the app which is set as the Entry point, then if you want to launch another app, we usually launch it by EntryApp. In addition, may I know how you used protocol to open uwp app?

Comment: i have set Protocol in package Declaration section have added Protocol from list and assign Name.

Comment: Did you add the Protocol in uwp app and launch it in Winform app? When I packaged them and could launch the uwp app in Winform app.

Comment: yes that is added but app will open for 2 second than i got error of in process my code is  Uri uri = new Uri("myvap:");
                var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
                psi.UseShellExecute = true;
                psi.FileName = uri.ToString();
                
                try
                {
                    Process.Start(psi);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                   string strText = ex.Message + ex.StackTrace;
                }

Comment: Getting this Exception - The app didn't start at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

Comment: I used you code in winform app and can launch uwp app successfully, I didn't receive the same issue. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?